# discord.py-rewrite Blacklist certain people from using the bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot similar to "Discord Deliver" and "Discord Byte" where people can order virtual food, and I want to be able to black list certain people from using the bot. Is there any way of doing this? For all my commands i use `@bot.command`; I am specifying this as some people use `on_message`. Sorry that I don't have anything I've tried, I am relatively new to discord.py-rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a set containing their names and exit the function if the command's author's name is in that set.

```
blacklist = {'name1', 'name2', 'name3'}

@bot.command()
async def command(ctx):
    if ctx.author.name in blacklist:
        return

    # do rest of command
```

Using a set instead of a list for `in` is better because the lookup time is O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: Do I put there username and tag? EX: DannyDevito#1234
Or user ID?

Comment: It's just their username. If you want to use their ID use ctx.author.id, and if the command is coming from a guild you can check for their nickname with ctx.author.nick. ctx.author.name will remain the same even if they change their nickname for a guild. As far as I know, tags aren't used in discord.py.

Comment: Actually, instead of using ctx.author.name I would highly recommend using ctx.author.id, because users can still change their name, but the only way to change their ID is to make a new account. [Here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-#:~:text=In%20the%20right%2Dclick%20menu,ID%20copied%20to%20your%20clipboard.) is how to get people's ID.

Comment: So i tested this and it does not work. It still does the rest of the command even if the user is blacklisted. I tried the user ID and name/name and tag, and it did not work.

Comment: Try printing ctx.author.name before the if statement and make sure you are only including their name and not their tag. Also, when using IDs the values in the blacklist have to be integers, so remove the quotes around them.

Comment: I tried JUST there username, and it still did not work.

Comment: What about the output of the print function? Is it what you put in the blacklist?

Comment: Yes. I printed the following `ctx.message.author` `ctx.author.id` `ctx.author.name` and tried blacklisting them all individually however that did not work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217286/discussion-between-keanu-and-echothealpha).